# pyQT slot decorator what is the C++ equivalent

Tags: c++, python, qt

I have a beginner level question on QT and PyQT. 
I am using PyQt bindings of Python and have the following simple code. Based on some google search, it seems that the slot decorator is used mainly for explicit marking of a method to a slot. My question is what will be the equivalent method if I am to write this code in C++?

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def openDialog(self):
        self.myDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a slot in C++/Qt, you use this syntax:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

public slots:
   void mySlot(/* parameters here */); // Definition may be here or in the implementation file
};
```

If you are using the no_keywords option (which means you don't want to use the Qt keywords as normal C++ keywords), just replace `slots` by `Q_SLOTS`

You'll find more information in the official documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html